# Problema ao criar projeto Maven no Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, java-ee, maven

Estava utilizando o o `Maven` no `Eclipse Luna` normalmente, resolvi testar a nova versão do Eclipse e quando crio um projeto `Maven` algumas exceções são lançadas:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed
>   out   pom.xml /Testando   line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema alterando as configurações de proxy do arquivo `settings.xml` que fica na pasta do `Maven`.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tentaria um mvn clean install -U.

Caso não funcione, tente apagar as dependências na pasta .m2 do seu usuário e execute mvn clean install novamente.

Comment: beleza, eu já apaguei as dependências da pasta .m2. Vou tentar fazer `mvn clean install -U.`

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, era problema como o proxy